# Swift animate CollectionView item on tap

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to animate my `CollectionViewCell` when it is `tapped`, kind of like in the AppStore. I managed to almost get the behavior but it is not 100% fluent:

Here is a [video](https://gofile.io/d/XkOJBg) for a better understanding.

If you look closely you can see that after tapping the `cell` is *shrinking* again for a small moment.

This is my code:

```
func shrink(down: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        if down {
            self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
        } else {
            self.theView.transform = .identity
        }
    }
}

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        shrink(down: isHighlighted)
    }
}
```

How can I solve the issue that the items is only shrinking once?
Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @Sh_Khan what for?  `isHighlited` is called twice when tapping it, I checked that

Comment: @Sh_Khan `print(isHighlighted)` in `didSet` is printing `true` & `false`

Comment: @Sh_Khan what do you mean? The `cell` should shrink down and up on tap. But as you can see in the video it is shrinking down up and down

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it: I had to set the `duration` different when it is shrinking or going back so I get a smooth transition:

```
func shrink(down: Bool) {
    if down {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.theView.transform = .identity
        }
        
    }
}

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        shrink(down: isHighlighted)
    }
}
```

This is how it looks now with the smooth transition:

https://gofile.io/d/dwnuCW

Here is a link to my app if you want to test the result:

https://apps.apple.com/de/app/wishlists-einfach-w%C3%BCnschen/id1503912334

Answer (score 2):

Use the following technique to achieve your effect – override `didHighlightItemAt` and `didUnhighlightItemAt` in your collection view delegate like so:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        cell?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        cell?.transform = .identity
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chris Where are you implementing that? It should be where your `cellForItem...` and all delegate & data sources methods are. Make sure your `delegate` is properly set up.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I actually managed to fix it by myself. Check out my answer